# Is there a way to start MobileSafari.app in the iPhone Simulator with a url

Tags: ios-simulator, mobile-safari

We'd like to test our site in as many browsers as we can in our Continuous Integration server, in ios as well. We'd like to start the ios simulator with opening safari a url. We can start safari this way:

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone\ Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/iPhone\ Simulator -SimulateApplication /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/Applications/MobileSafari.app/MobileSafari

But we haven't figured it out yet how to give the url as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

try -u:

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone\ Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/iPhone\ Simulator -SimulateApplication /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/Applications/MobileSafari.app/MobileSafari -u http://www.google.com

Comment: It starts the safari app but doesn't open the url.

Comment: strange. It works for me. Make sure, that Safari is not already started.

Comment: tried with both fresh start and existing safari running - no diff ;(

Comment: doesn't work for me either (I've tried -u before asking it here with iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk, now I'm on iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk, and it doesn't work with this version as well). If I close the simulator with an opened safari running google for example, it is surely starts with google opened next time, maybe you tried that way?

Comment: -u opens the URL in the browser, the path to MobileSafari is a red herring. This works just as well: `/path/to/simulator -u http://www.google.com`

Answer (score 0):

It works Jan command, but you must correct the path to the SDK "iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk".
I run the command to iOS 7 SDK and every time page which i want to open - is opened.